# How can I import a GPX file in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, import, expo, gpx

I need to import a GPX file into my React application for downloading. However, I have encountered some problems and can't find solutions. I can't use RNFS from react-native-fs because it is not recognized by Expo. I also can't simply import, require, or fetch any .gpx file because .gpx files are not recognized by React Native.

If someone has a solution for this problem, I would appreciate your assistance.

I try :

- RNFS
- import
- require
- fetch

Comment: I resolved my issue by using FileSystem.documentDirectory from expo-file-system. The process is as follows: I import all my .gpx files into FileSystem.documentDirectory or FileSystem.cacheDirectory during the download synchronization or a specific process. Then, I can directly access the .gpx files located in FileSystem.documentDirectory + "mygpx.gpx".